# When should we recite Ayat ul Kursi after fard salah?

Tags: hadith, salat, fard

Sometimes I forget to recite ayat ul kursi after my fard salah so I recite it 1 or 2 minutes later. Is the respective hadith still applicable if I don't recite it immediately after the salah?